# Задержка времени в pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtimer

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатию на кнопку через некоторое время выполнялась функция?

`time.sleep(...)` не подходит.

Так же как у `tkinter after(ms, func)` или у `js setTimeout(ms, func)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `QTimer` Class
>
> Класс `QTimer` предоставляет повторяющиеся и одиночные таймеры.
>
> `singleShot` : bool
>
> Это свойство определяет, является ли таймер однократным Таймер однократного срабатывания срабатывает только один раз, таймеры не однократного срабатывания - каждые миллисекунды. Значением по умолчанию для этого свойства является false.

```
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.my_func)
```

---

**Update**

> У меня почему-то ошибка self.wordButton.clicked.connect(lambda: QTimer.singleShot(2, print(1))) TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call: singleShot(int, PYQT_SLOT): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType' singleShot(int, Qt.TimerType, PYQT_SLOT): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

```
    self.wordButton.clicked.connect(self.onWordButton) 

def onWordButton(self):
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: print(1))
```

Comment: У меня почему-то ошибка    self.wordButton.clicked.connect(lambda: QTimer.singleShot(2000, print(1)))

TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  singleShot(int, PYQT_SLOT): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  singleShot(int, Qt.TimerType, PYQT_SLOT): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Comment: @Injustive я ответил на ваш вопрос, почему вы сняли пометку что ответ правильный ? Так делать не правильно! У вас еще много будет ошибок, так что вы их будите все перечислять в донном вопросе? Смотрите дополнение к первому ответу.

Comment: Извините, случайно получилось, обычно так не делаю.